# 2d point to 3d point on a sphere

Tags: math, 3d

i haven’t been entirely sure what to google or search for to help solve my problem, really hoping someone here can help a little…

currently i have a 3d scene, it has a massive sphere with a texture mapped to it and the camera at the center of the sphere, so it’s much like a qtvr viewer.

i’d like a way to click on the polygons within the sphere and update the texture at that position with something and dot etc..

the only part of the process where i need help is converting the 2d mouse position to a point on the inside of the sphere.

hope this makes sense…

fyi, im only looking for a pure math solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is convert the screen coordinate into a line in 3d space. This will pass through the point you click and your eyepoint.

Once you have this line you can then intersect this line with your sphere to find the intersection point on the sphere.

Comment: so cast a ray and check intersection point on sphere? cool thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may get 2d coordinates of the polygons (triangles?) that are making up the sphere and then find the one that contains the mouse pointer point.